# Is updating npm dependencies not recommended on a production application?

Tags: node.js, npm

I recently started exploring npm and installed a github repo `yoonic/nicistore`.

But when I try to build it fails.

My question is if I start building things on top of node, which I see has tooo many dependencies from different vendors, Am I completely on the mercy of the respective package developers?

I have seen that most node based github repos fail to build in the first try.  If I update one of the modules by running a console command, Is it likely to break all the application?

And if It is does, doesn't it prove node.js an unreliable and unstable development platform?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Think of it as the opposite of most other languages.

You are writing an app in Java.
You want to use LibA, LibB and LibC.

So you try to use LibC 2.4, and as soon as you do, your manager throws all kinds of errors at you.
Why?

Because LibB is using LibC 1.9

So now what are your options?
Strip out all of the calls to all of the new API for LibC that you wanted to use...
...or hope that LibB is open-source, and you can contribute an update for a new version of it, so that you can use the latest version of LibC (and hope *it* doesn't update).

So now you've done that... but now you've broken your LibA, because it wants the old LibB.

You didn't even *want* LibA, you just had to have it for your app to be happy with your framework, and the libs that you *did* actually want to use (B and C). LibA is closed-source, and isn't maintained, anymore. Tough luck. Go back to your old ways, and forget about how much better life could be, if you could only use your framework with the new version of LibC. Or start praying that your framework does a major rewrite, to get rid of the LibA dependency... but then figure out what new hell you have to deal with, just to get LibC working.

Is this really better than Node?
What node allows you to do is install dependencies which are at different versions than the same library that your dependencies are using.

Not that you can't do that with Java, too... but the entire community has decided that it's just not ever going to try to do that, and thus outlaw it at a tool level.

---

Next, you see too many things which leave you at the mercy of too many vendors...
Going back to Java (or C++, or nearly any mainstream language), looking at Java, itself, how many libraries are made by Sun Microsystems, or by James Gosling?

Moreover, if you want to boil it down, to suggest using only, say, one huge, overarching framework (like Spring MVC) and using no other libraries of any kind (like JodaTime), then how many libraries does Spring itself lean on, and why are they of no concern to you, even if you're just using the compiled VM bytecode?

In fact, a strong argument could be made to be more wary of compiled binaries, in languages where it was traditional to see strong, copy-left licensing like that of the GNU GPL... in that realm, you open yourself up to craziness.
Most of the Node stuff, by comparison, is dirt-simple freeware. And even if it's not, it's quickly replaceable as most are micro-libraries.

---

I would suggest that updating a Node package your server depends on, via CLI is less hazardous than doing the same to a full-fledged Java project, if your goal is to see your project compile again, some time in the next week, but with the newer fixes/features...

...but if you're talking about a full-scale, production application, you also want to be cognizant of what it is you're doing, with regards to your codebase, regardless.

---

As to why things don't build for you on the first try, assuming that you're on a non-Windows platform, and your environment is up to date, I don't know.
Most C/C++ projects I clone don't build for me, first try, either. I usually forget something, or there was something poorly documented, or the actual project was set up to make unfair assumptions about the system it would operate in.

Does that mean that C++ is an unreliable/unstable development platform?
Or the hours/days spent on getting Eclipse set up in an enterprise environment, with all kinds of crazy, company-specific projects and project settings?

It sounds like a case of bad design, more than anything.

Then again, most of my projects these days are wrapped in Docker containers. They all run in the same environment, whether they're running in Windows, on a Mac, or on the server. That tends to take the sting out of building projects, regardless of what language the code is in, or what VM / processor they're running on.

You should also be using NPM shrinkwrap files, or Yarn Lockfiles to preserve the build configuration, with the known-working versions of libraries. And you should have unit and integration tests to ensure that changing library versions has no discernible impact on your system.

Comment: shrinkwrap is a great suggestion! Though SO says avoid thanks, I can't stop myself saying it for this great article.